# 'Undefined' in Angular 2 Observables and Http

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I find using observables with http in angular 2 really difficult. 
In the below code, I get the `in method:` value printed in console successfully. But `Main:` is `undefined` when I tried to print .

How can I get the value from `Main`?

Template code:

```
template:`
<input 
        class="form-control"
      [formControl]="searchBox" 
      placeholder="Search Spotify artist" />
`
```

Component code:

```
export class SpotifySearchComponent {

  private searchBox = new FormControl();

  constructor(private _http: Http){

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {    
    var keyups = this.searchBox
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(200)
        .map(searchTerm => {
            this.getResults(searchTerm);           
        });

    var subscription = keyups.subscribe(res => console.log("Main:" + res));       
  }

  getResults(searchTerm){           
      console.log("in method:" + searchTerm);
      return searchTerm;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement in the `map` block.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {    
    var keyups = this.searchBox
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(200)
        .map(searchTerm => {
            return this.getResults(searchTerm);           
        });

    var subscription = keyups.subscribe(res => console.log("Main:" + res));       
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from your `map` function. It should be either

```
.map(searchTerm => {
    return this.getResults(searchTerm);           
}
```

or

```
.map(searchTerm => this.getResults(searchTerm))
```